# logical subset from a matrix based on multiple columns with no names

Tags: r, subset

I am reading in data which has 112 variables and 1000 observations from text files in a data.frame format,  and want to select only those rows that have positive numbers in columns 17:34 and 40, 42, 45, and 47:91.

for evaluating columns from 17 to 34, i used this, and it did not work.

```
mydata= subset(mydata,mydata[,17:34] > 0 )
```

How can I fix the problem, and refer to all these columns I want to evaluate in a compact way?

I also tried using loops like below, and it worked, but I wonder if there is a more simple way of writing this.

```
for (i in 17:34){
mydata= subset(mydata,mydata[,i] > 0 ) 
}
mydata= subset(mydata,mydata[,40] > 0 ) 
mydata= subset(mydata,mydata[,42] > 0 ) 
mydata= subset(mydata,mydata[,45] > 0 ) 
for (i in 47:91){
  mydata= subset(mydata,mydata[,i] > 0 ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on the non-positive logical matrix, negate it and subset the rows.

```
Subdf <- mydata[!rowSums(mydata[,c(17:34,40, 42, 45, 47:91)]<=0),]
```

Using a small reproducible example

```
set.seed(24)
mydata <- matrix(sample(-5:40, 10*30, replace=TRUE), ncol=10)
Subdf <- mydata[!rowSums(mydata[, c(1, 5, 7)]<=0),]
Subdf[,c(1,5,7)]
```